# How many bridge hands contain five spades, four hearts, three clubs, and one diamonds?

Tags: probability

The way I think for this problem is as follows:

There are

$$\binom{13}{5}$$

ways for the spades

and

$$\binom{13}{4}$$

ways for the hearts

and

$$\binom{13}{3}$$

ways for the clubs

and

$$\binom{13}{1}$$

for the diamonds.

So the total ways should be

$$\binom{13}{5}\times\binom{13}{4}\times\binom{13}{3}\times\binom{13}{1}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks right to me...

Comment: The comment of @5xum looks right to me...:)

Comment: Sure, you're right. To show it more intuitively: you have $5$ reserved places for spades , $4$ for hearts and so on and each group of places is filled from its own $13$-element set and as the places are reserved a priori, you may consider them separately, getting $\binom{13}{5}$ for spades, $\binom{13}{4}$ for hearts and so on. The last thing you need to find the answer is to mix these groups of cards in all possible ways and number of these ways is definitely a product of all those binomials, as group length are constant and, as we noticed above, each group uses its own card set.

Comment: Is binomial the same thing as combination?